# prove or disprove $(-1)^n(n+1)\equiv n+1\pmod 4$

Tags: number-theory

when I read a book,they say this is clear:

let $n$ be postive integer,then have
$$(-1)^n(n+1)\equiv n+1\pmod 4$$
Why don't I feel right?

Comment: Well, just check.  There are only $4$ possible things $n$ can be $\pmod 4$.

Comment: I am pretty sure you did not make an effort. Such questions can get downvoted and closed.

Comment: It is $\pm(n+1)$ the sign depending if $n$ is odd or even.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ is even $(-1)^n=1$ and $(-1)^n(n+1)=(n+1)$

if $n=2p+1$, $(-1)^n(n+1)=-(2p+2)$.

$(-1)^n(n+1)-(n+1)=-(2p+2)-(2p+2)=-4p-4$.

Answer (score 2):

Their difference $\,\underbrace{(n+1)\overbrace{(1 - (-1)^{\large n})}^{\large 0 \ \ {\rm if}\ \ n\ \ {\rm even}}}_{\large {\rm even}\ \times\ 2\ \ {\rm if}\ \ n\ \ {\rm odd}\!\!\!}\ $ is divisible by $\,4\,$ so they are congruent $\!\bmod{4}$.